# Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException :in command prompt

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, stsadm

I am using stsadm command to deactivate a feature. Here is the command i used:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN>stsa
dm -o deactivatefeature -filename "ZippingOption\feature.xml" -url "http://print
ing"`

This is the error i am getting:

> **Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.**

Can any one have the solution for this...?

Comment: I'm assuming ZippingOption is a custom feature? Can you post the code that runs when the feature is deactivating?